# How to typeset rare Chinese characters?

Tags: symbols, chinese

While the around 6,000 common Chinese characters can be supported by the `CJK` package (or the `ctex` family of documentclasses) well, what if I want to type some (relatively) rare Chinese characters (it is said that there are about 60,000 Chinese characters in total) which, for example, appeared in ancient poems and documents?

For instance, today I tried typesetting the following characters

> 玕, 襜褕, 雰雰

in a poem under the `CJK` environment (later I changed my documentclass to `ctexbook`), I can't see them in the output pdf document.

I believe there probably are some ways to handle this issue in LaTeX, but I don't know how to carry out these potential solutions to get my missing (but important) characters printed out.

A google search leads me to a [reference](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-3/wong.pdf) aiming to solve this problem. The solution therein looks promising in theory, however, I was not able to find the `HanGlyph` package described in this paper from CTAN so the implementation is still a problem.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could provide me with some guidelines (I am making a document that collects Chinese ancient poems. Therefore, the chance that I met these rare characters is pretty high.).

---

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}
美人赠我琴琅玕

美人赠我襜褕貂

欲往从之雰雰雪
\end{document}
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: ShareLaTeX, now Overleaf, can compile with pdftex, xetex, or luatex. If you have a font that supports the characters (try DejaVu, Noto, etc.), you can use it with xetex or luatex.

Comment: Later I learned that too. Now I am compiling with XeLaTeX. In the meantime, I changed to the `ctexbook` document class. However, the main problem, as stated in the question, still persists.

Comment: I tried `CJK` package with pdfLaTeX and `ctexbook` class with XeLaTeX, and both produced those characters in the output. Could you show us [a minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) to help us help you?

Comment: @yudai-nkt Sure, please see my edited question. Again, I used ShareLaTeX as my compiler.

Comment: I confirmed the issue using Overleaf [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/mynkbspqnrbb), but your MWE gave the desired PDF on my Mac. The difference is the fonts in use (FandolSong in Overleaf and STSong on Mac), so the problem is that FandolSong does not have glyphs for these characters. So you need to use an appropriate font as @Thérèse says, but I don't know how to do that in ShareLaTeX because for example STSong and Source Han Serif are not shipped with TeX Live.

Comment: @yudai-nkt Thanks, your explanation makes sense. I tried in my mac but it still didn't work out (I even can't compile my tex file). I guess this is because I haven't configured my TeX Live in my mac for a while (I switched to ShareLaTeX two years ago). I will try to install required packages/fonts manually tomorrow to see if it works. The installation on Mac is very tricky (I accidentally removed my earlier MacTeX versions, which costs me cannot compile the tex file at all).

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you so much. I solved my problem according to your guidance. If you like, you can expand your comment to an answer so I can upvote and accept it!

Comment: Another relevant reference: [Using your favourite fonts with ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/04/02/using-your-favourite-fonts-with-sharelatex.html). And on my computer, all the characters in `玕, 襜褕, 雰雰` are contained in the following fonts: `Arial Unicode` `Hiragino Sans GB` `LastResort` `NISC18030` `NotoSansCJKjp` `NotoSansCJKkr` `NotoSansCJKsc` `NotoSansCJKtc` `NotoSansMonoCJKjp` `NotoSansMonoCJKkr` `NotoSansMonoCJKsc` `NotoSansMonoCJKtc` `PingFang` `STHeiti`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know whether any fonts available for use with pdftex contain the characters you need. But if you compile with luatex or xetex rather than pdftex, then you can choose any `.otf` or `.ttf` font with these characters and load it with `fontspec`. This [Unicode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8d60/fontsupport.htm) can help you find appropriate fonts; if you’re interested in purchasing a commercial typeface, [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/) allows you to search by character, as explained [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/63290/51768).

Having chosen a typeface, you can either install it on your system or, if you are compiling on-line at [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/), upload it [as described in Overleaf’s help pages](https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this). Unless it is one of [the many fonts already available on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/help/193-what-otf-slash-ttf-fonts-are-supported-via-fontspec), you will then refer to the font by its file name when you invoke `fontspec`, as in Mico’s example.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need a font that provides all needed glyphs. `SimHei` may just be such a font. The font features a bit more than 28,000 glyphs, the vast majority of which would appear to be Chinese characters.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SimHei.ttf}

\begin{document}
美人赠我琴琅玕

美人赠我襜褕貂

欲往从之雰雰雪
\end{document}
```

Comment: SimHei is available only on Windows among major platforms, and is unusable on ShareLaTeX unfortunately.

Comment: @yudai-nkt - Thanks for this information. FWIW, I compiled the code above on a MacOS 10.13.3 system running MacTeX2017. The font file is located at `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/SimHei.ttf`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that because I still use El Capitan and some Linux. Maybe Apple added SimHei in Sierra or High Sierra.